# Mandelbrot Set in a fragment shader version 330

Tags: opengl, glsl, fractals

I am trying to to make a Mandelbrot set on the fragment shader. I initially build a rectangle, and use the gl_FragCoords to calculate the algorithm. Here is the code:

```
#version 330 core

uniform float MaxIterations;

out vec4 pixelColor;

void main()
{
    float   real  = gl_FragCoord.x;
    float   imag  = gl_FragCoord.y;
    float   Creal = real;  
    float   Cimag = imag;  

    float r2 = 0.0;

    for (float iter = 0.0; iter < MaxIterations && r2 < 4.0; ++iter)
    {
        float tempreal = real;

        real = (tempreal * tempreal) - (imag * imag) + Creal;
        imag = 2.0 * tempreal * imag + Cimag;
        r2   = (real * real) + (imag * imag);
    }

    vec3 color;

    if (r2 < 4.0)
        color = vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    else
        color = vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    pixelColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

This code is actually kind of simplified and adapted version of what I found on the internet. I just assume the y axis as the imaginary and the x axis as the real part. Then I calculate the iterations until a max value passed by an uniform. It should show a black and white rectangle (white outside of the set, and black inside), but I just get a white rectangle. Does anybody knows what is wrong?

EDIT: to add a little bit more detail.
Here is the vertices I used for the rectangle

```
GLfloat vertices[] = {
        0.9f, 0.9f,     
        0.9f, -0.9f,    
        -0.9f, -0.9f, 
        -0.9f, 0.9f 
    };
```

and here is the vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec2 position;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

Comment: What you have looks right. Are you sure it's applying your shader? If you change the "not in the set" color to something like red or yellow, does the entire thing turn red or yellow?

Comment: yes, I changed to red now and I get a red rectangle

Comment: When I'm in this situation, I check my assumptions. If you output the fragment coordinates (maybe scaled and offset so they're visible), are they what you expect?

Comment: What is the output of the iteration for test data like (0,0i), (-1,0i), which are surely part of the set? (so those points should be black)

Comment: I think bofjas's answer is correct. `gl_FragCoord` contains window relative coordinates, so the entire set is mapped to one pixel (probably in the lower left of your rectangle).

Comment: Ok, When I get home I will try what he said. Now that I think of, since I am using a window 800x600, my coordinates are really big in magnitude (x axis goes up to 800 pixels), so using the coordinates from vertices[] would be more precise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't the pixel coordinates somewhat large input values for a mandlebrot set? Try creating a new output from the vertex shader representing the vertex coordinates and use that as a input in the fragment shader:

```
layout (location = 0) in vec2 position;
out vec2 coord;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    coord = position.xy
}
```

And in the fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core

uniform float MaxIterations;

out vec4 pixelColor;
in vec2 coord;

void main()
{
    float   real  = coord.x;
    float   imag  = coord.y;

(...)
```

Comment: Awesome tip :). I worked just fine. So the problem was that my coordinates were really big in magnitude, so the absolute value would always be bigger than 4.0. Now using the values from the declared array vertices[] it works just fine.